# Haskell cycle a vector

Tags: haskell, vector

Is there a vector alternative of Data.List's [cycle](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:cycle)?

The Data.Vector docs have a section titled [Recycling support](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/vector-0.9.1/docs/Data-Vector-Generic.html#g:41) that sounds like it is what I would want but the functions `new` and `clone` clearly don't do what `cycle` does.

The solution I was thinking about is just repeatedly index the vector with  (a counter mod the length of the vector).

An example of what I needed to do, is I need an infinite list of randomly shuffled grids, but the grids are large and so keeping millions of them in memory is not ideal. I realized that it did not matter if the cycle of random was relatively small, so instead I generated a list of only a couple hundred grids and then used `Data.List.cycle` to give the illusion of infinite length. I am now converted the `list` of grids to a `Vector` of grids and can no longer use `cycle`.

Comment: Can you give a concrete example of what you want to do?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No.  The existing Vector's in the Vector package allocate at least the spine and thus you can not have `Vector.cycle` without infinite memory.

For example, `Data.Vector` uses `Data.Primitive.Array`.

Since the internals of the vector package (e.g. `Data.Vector.Generic.*`) allow you to define other types of Vectors in a flexible manner, you could make a vector type that computes the index modulo the length to provide cyclic behavior (and includes an offset for use with `drop`).  So the construction is conceivable, just not done.

Answer (score 2):

If you want a finite representation of cyclic lists (not vectors so you'll still have an access time linear in the size of the cycle), you may want to have a look at [this module](https://github.com/gallais/potpourri/blob/master/haskell/cyclic/CyclicListFlat.hs) I was playing with last year.

By the way, the reason why [the type of fold](https://github.com/gallais/potpourri/blob/master/haskell/cyclic/CyclicListFlat.hs#L150) is quite weird is [explained here](http://gallais.github.io/blog/cyclic-list-purely). Basically the idea is that we may or may not decide to unfold the cycle depending on whether we use the induction hypothesis given to us.